# Log in to Pi static IP, but no monitor

Tags: networking

I just moved to a new flat where the router uses the 10(...) address-space, rather than 192(...). Unfortunately, I gave my Pi a static IP starting with 192 and now I cannot log in as I don't have a monitor with HDMI-in.

SSH is configured, but can't log in with the old static address. And the Pi doesn't show up in the network.

I do have a wireless keyboard that I can plug in and use perhaps use to switch back to dynamic IP. But I would have to do it blind... Can anyone think of a way around this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the Raspberry Pi's SD card into your computer and modify the settings on your computer. Make sure to use an editor such as [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org) so the files remain readable by Raspbian. Open /etc/network/interfaces on your computer, and add these lines:

```
address 10.x.x.x
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 10.x.x.x
broadcast 10.x.x.x
gateway 10.x.x.x
```

Save the file and boot your Pi and hopefully it works!

[This site](http://www.modmypi.com/blog/tutorial-how-to-give-your-raspberry-pi-a-static-ip-address) has a guide on using the same method to set a static IP (however just edit the files on your computer, instead of the Pi of course.)

Answer (score 5):

Manually change the IP address of your other computer to one on the 192... address space.  Then ssh to the Pi using the Pi's static IP address.

Once you are logged in via ssh change the IP on the PI to a new static address on the 10... network or change it to use DHCP.

You will then need to change the IP of your other computer back to whatever it was.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a mac, take a look at the locations options, where you can create different network configurations.  With this you can easily switch between different network configurations like `static 192.168.0.0`, `static 10.0.0.0`, etc.

Using this trick, make a `static 192.168.0.0` location and then update your ethernet configuration to match the network that your RPi is on.  Then plug the RPi's network cable directly into your computer and SSH in.

Once you're done configuring your RPi, easily switch your computer's network settings back by selecting the previous location in the pulldown.

[image: mac network locations]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions. I couldn't use SSH as the Pi wasn't connected to the new wifi. But I found a solution:

I plugged the SD-card from the Pi into my laptop's card reader and installed a program called Paragon that let me see all the Pi's Linux files.

With the files visible, I could navigate to the network files and change the address space, assign a new static IP and log in to the network. That let me log in through SSH. This method should work fine if you have a SD-card reader, but no monitor.